How to calculate wing deflection?
I can calculate deflection for a single beam, but I do not know how to calculate deflection for the whole wing section. I do not know how to calculate deflection for the two spars simultaneously.
I am guessing that I can calculate the deflection of each spar independently and then make both have the same deflection to avoid internal stresses inside the wing structure. Another option that comes to mind is to calculate Moments around both spars and thus obtain a single Moment equation for both spars that can be integrated to get deflection. This can be achieved since both spars have the same Young Modulus. Would that be a proper way to calculate both spar's deflection?
The above makes me wonder how to calculate the deflection of a cantilever composite spar. What happens if the materials that make up the wing section have different E and G values? Just like an accurate entire wing section, D-tube plus spars plus shear webs, etc?
Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

I fear that a proper answer to your question would need a lot of text and equations. Any book about aircraft structures should help you - semimonocoque theory is the keyword to your answer.

I  have read only Timoshenko's, I will look into Bruhn's. Thanks!

You can also read something more updated ;-)

Thanks for the link sophit!
